# Apparent paradox in time difference between Kate and Alex

Tags: plot-explanation, the-lake-house

I understand that [*The Lake House* (2006)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lake_House_(film)) has a lot of paradox. I understand the time traveling thing, there is just one thing that I don’t understand. At the beginning of the movie, Alex and Kate are writing their letters near the mailbox. They receive them immediately and are surprised and shocked.

Why can’t they see each other? If this is because of the time gap, then why can they see each other at the end of the movie?

Comment: Related (if not even duplicate): [Wouldn't two years for him be two years for her as well?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/59074/49)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - more comprehensive than mine, which was pretty much just from memory.

Answer (score 2):

There's no actual 'time travel' other than for letters in the mailbox. Everything else is just that we are being show two 'presents', one in 2004 & the other in 2006, unfolding to the audience mainly in parallel.

Think of the mailbox as a kind of 'time tunnel'.
You can't see through it, but anything you put in there at, say 12 noon on Feb 13 2004 will immediately arrive 2 years later at 12 noon on Feb 13 2006, and vice versa. A little extra 'magic' is that the mailbox flag automatically registers these mails. I guess that's just to save the tedious repetition of going to the box every five minutes to see if there's anything new in it.

All that's required to support this is a little 'willing suspension of disbelief'. After that the plot vehicle works quite well. It's a simple rule.

This simple rule appears to have been broken when Kate discovers Alex was killed two years earlier… I think their ace in the plot hole here is we don't know the exact date and time.

On Valentine's Day 2008, she suddenly realises what is about to happen two years earlier & passes one final note, telling Alex not to come to find her on Feb 14 2006, but come to the Lake House on Feb 14 2008 instead. We're not initially shown whether or not he receives this note, that's our happy ending plot twist.

This appears to break the paradox, as he receives the note in time to change his plans, and goes to the Lake House instead, two years later, just as told.
Cue happy ending.
We kind of have to ignore that Alex must have been sitting twiddling his thumbs for the intervening two years.